# C# Adding Tasks to a Folder in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, task, directory

I have a need to add tasks that I programmatically create into a folder within Outlook.

I have code that creates a task and I also have code that creates a folder. This works fine.

Now the tricky part, how can I add my newly created task (the task is an object in memory at this point) to my newly created folder (Or just a folder in general)?

At this point I am looking to just add them to a folder, however in Outlook I am able to create a 'folder' like item that I can create tasks in (see attached screenshot). I would love to really be able to do this programmatically instead of a folder.

[image: Task Folder Image]

Does anyone have examples or documentation that could possible point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to a [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863890.aspx), you can use [`Folder.Items.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028.aspx) to create a [`TaskItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867891.aspx) in that `Folder`. 
If you used [`Application.CreateItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb219889%28v=office.12%29.aspx), then you should use [`TaskItem.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869122.aspx) to move the item into a specific `Folder`.